# What is the collective name for the digits before and after decimal point?

Tags: terminology, number-systems

What is the collective name for the digits before and after decimal point?

[image]

Comment: Integer and fractional parts.

Comment: I have heard of both "integer part" as well as "integral part" for the part to the left of the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

The part before the decimal point, the whole number $120$ in your example, is often referred to as the Characteristic and can be seen here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Characteristic.html. The part after the decimal point, the fractional part $590$ in your example, can be referred to as the Mantissa. More information on this can be found here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wolfram Mathworld has a number of nonstandard definitions, but these are also mentioned [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm#cite_ref-5) and I've seen at least "mantissa" in use elsewhere (I believe in discussions of [Benford's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)).

Answer (score -2):

It's called the Number of Significant Figures.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: No.  Not at all.

Comment: In this example, all of $120.590$ are significant figures, but that is not how the different parts of this number are called. The question is asking about the names of the different collections of digits.